# Best practice for SVG with png fallback on w3 validation

Tags: svg

What is the best way of adding an svg logo with a png fallback that is w3 valid

I am currently using:

```
<svg width="282" height="96">
                        <image xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/Content/Images/logo.svg" src="/Content/Images/logo.png" width="282" height="96"></image>
                    </svg>
```